# Prove that $f$ reaches a minimum on a compact space for a (possibly) non-continous function

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

> Let $(X,\tau)$ be a topological **compact** space.
>
> Consider $f:X\to \mathbb{R}$ which has the following property
>   $$(\forall x \in X)(\exists V_x \text{ neighbourhood of } x)(f(x) = \min_{y\in V_x} f(y))$$
>
> Prove that $f$ attains a minimum on $X$

I came up with the following proof, but some questions remain:

#### Proof:

Consider for each $x$ the neighbourhood $V_x$ where the special property holds. Then

$$(\forall x \in X)(\exists U_x\in \tau)(x\in U_x\subseteq V_x)(f(x) = \min_{y\in U_x} f(y))$$

Now consider the open cover $\bigcup_{x\in X} U_x$ of $X$. Since $X$ is compact this cover has a finite subcover. Say $\bigcup_{i\in I} U_{x_i}$ where each $f(x_i) = \min_{y\in U_{x_i}} f(y)$.

Then $\min_{i\in I} f(x_i) = \min_{x\in X} f(x)$.

#### Two questions:

1. Am I right that these don't have to be constant functions?

   When using the discrete topology $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}; x\mapsto x$ would have this *special property*, right? (since each $\{ x\}$ would be its own neighbourhood)
2. I think the proof is right, but I wonder why I can be sure I don't lose the minimum when taking the finite subcover. Why can I be sure I didn't remove that minimum when reducing the subcovers?

Comment: It is still a cover, so you still have the entire space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A discrete topological space has the "every point is a minimum of one of its neighborhoods" property, but it is only compact if the underlying set is finite. (This is one of the precise ways that compactness is a "generalization of finiteness".)

Your proof covers $X$ by the special neighborhoods $V_x$, then finds a finite subcover $\{ V_{x_i} \}_{i=1}^n$. Now $f(x_i) \leq f(y)$ for all $y \in V_{x_i}$. Now if $x_i$ has the smallest value of $f(x_j)$ among $j=1,\dots,n$, then $f(x_j)$ is the smallest value over all of $X$. That's because:

1. $f(x_j) \leq f(y)$ for every $j$ and every $y \in V_{x_j}$
2. $f(x_i) \leq f(x_j)$ for every $j$
3. By combining 1 and 2 you get $f(x_i) \leq f(y)$ for every $j$ and every $y \in V_{x_j}$. So you get it for every $y \in X$ since the $V$'s are a cover.

Answer (score 0):

Shorter proof: $f$ is lower semicontinuous, and a lower semicontinuous function on a compact space attains a minimum.